# Why are Gabriel categories closed under localization?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal K$ be a Grothendieck category. [Recall](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462398/example-of-a-grothendieck-category-which-is-not-gabriel) the Gabriel filtration $0 \subseteq \mathcal K_1 \subseteq \cdots \mathcal K$ of localizing subcategories, where $\mathcal K_{\alpha+1}$ is generated by $\mathcal K_\alpha$ along with the finite-length objects of $\mathcal K^\alpha := \mathcal K / \mathcal K_\alpha$ (and if $\alpha$ is limit then $\mathcal K_\alpha$ is generated by the $\mathcal K_\beta$ for $\beta < \alpha$). If $\mathcal K_\alpha = \mathcal K$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, then $\mathcal K$ is said to be a *Gabriel category* and $\alpha$ is its *Gabriel dimension*.

In *des categories abeliennes*, Gabriel asserts without proof (Section IV, Prop 1 — note that he says “Krull dimension” instead of “Gabriel dimension”) that if $\mathcal K$ is a Gabriel category and $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal K$ is a localizing subcategory, then $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal K / \mathcal T$ are both Gabriel categories.

**Question:** How does one prove this (that Gabriel categories are stable under localization)?

- Gabriel says it follows from the definitions. But I’m at a loss: the definition of $\mathcal K_{\alpha+1}$ seems to me to be quite sensitive to the structure of $\mathcal K / \mathcal K_\alpha$, so I’m having difficulty relating the Gabriel filtration of $\mathcal K$ to the Gabriel filtration of $\mathcal K / \mathcal T$ or to that of $\mathcal T$.
- As a further clue, Gabriel also asserts that
  $$max(dim(\mathcal T), dim(\mathcal K / \mathcal T)) \leq dim(\mathcal K) \leq dim(\mathcal T) + dim(\mathcal K / \mathcal T),$$
  which really suggests the proof is supposed to do with some kind of elementary splicing together of Gabriel filtrations (especially since that’s an ordinal sum! See the notation at the beginning of Section IV.), but I am quite confused.
- An analogous question one category level down would be whether hypoabelian groups are stable under quotients. The answer here is *no*: free groups are hypoabelian.

Comment: Isn't $\mathcal{K}$ Gabriel iff it has no proper quotient by a localizing subcategory that has no simple modules? In which case, it is clear that $\mathcal{K}$ Gabriel implies $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{T}$ Gabriel (and hypoabelian groups are stable under subgroups!) But the same argument doesn't show that $\mathcal{K}$ Gabriel implies $\mathcal{T}$ Gabriel.

Comment: For the other implications and inequalities, I think you need to consider a looser kind of filtration than the Gabriel filtration, where $\mathcal{K}_{\alpha+1}/\mathcal{K}_\alpha$ is generated by simple objects as a localizing subcategory of $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{K}_\alpha$, but not necessarily all the available simple objects. Such a looser filtration may grow strictly more slowly than the Gabriel filtration, but should give an upper bound for the Gabriel dimension. And I think that splicing, and intersecting the Gabriel flitration of $\mathcal{K}$ with $\mathcal{T}$ does work now.

Comment: Sorry, I won't have time for a few days to work out the details, but I'd be happy for anybody else to do so in the meantime, Or to point out why this won't work!

Comment: Henning Kause, in Chapter 14 of his book [Homological Theory of Representations](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~hkrause/HomTheRep.html), covers the “small” version of all this (i.e., for Serre, rather than localizing, subcategories of small abelian categories) in some detail. I’m not sure if there are added difficulties in the “localizing” case.